# display single image in fullscreen mode (like powerpoint)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to open an image in fullscreen to overlap the taskbar and show no menu bar using python.

I got it to work using Tkinter with following code, but since its just a single image that does not need to be updated (ever), the blocking loop of `mainloop()` is **very** inconvenient and unnecessary. However, I can't get tkinter to stay open without that update loop. I've tried using `root.after()` to run the function afterwards but that froze my program (and isn't really what I want to do anyway)

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.update_idletasks()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.overrideredirect(1)
output = self.create_image_from_array(image_array)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=root.winfo_width(), height=root.winfo_height())
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=output, anchor="nw")
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
# after freezes my window
# root.after(0,someFunction)
# main loop blocking the function.
root.mainloop()
```

How can I display a single image on the entire screen using python (in both windows and linux) or how can I "pause" the tkinter loop to prevent the window from closing and updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you will have to handle tkinter's thread yourself rather than relying on `mainloop()`. Here is one way to do it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import time

class SomeFunc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running=True
        t = Thread(target=self.func)
        t.start()

    def func(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.update_idletasks()
        #root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        #root.overrideredirect(1)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=self.root.winfo_width(), height=self.root.winfo_height())
        #canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=output, anchor="nw")
        canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        while self.running:
            self.root.update()

a = SomeFunc()
x = 10
while x:
    x-=1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: so "freezing" tkinter is not an option then?
Some people wrote that putting tkinter into a non-main thread is not a good idea, does that apply here as well or just in special cases?

Comment: If you are only going to display a image in tkinter, it shouldn’t matter.